# I can't get the extras that I put into an intent, that I put in a "addProximityAlert"

Tags: java, android, methods, android-intent, proximity

I can't get the extras that I put into an intent, that I put in a "addProximityAlert"

```
locationNotific.putExtra("name", "ofek");

   // sendBroadcast(locationNotific); (I can get the extras)

    PendingIntent lPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, locationNotific, 0);

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SendProximityIntent"); 

       registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);


    lm.addProximityAlert((double) locationAlertGeoP.getLatitudeE6(),(double) locationAlertGeoP.getLongitudeE6(), (float) 999999999,(long) 100000,lPendingIntent);
```

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    IDForNotificationString = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    //MA.notification(IDForNotificationString);
```

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. If you have additional information, edit your original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in your `getBroadcast()` call, to merge in your extras with any that were in any previous `PendingIntent` for this same core `Intent`.

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: @ofeking109: Read the documentation for `getBroadcast()`, see where flags go, and type in `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to replace your `0`.